# Understanding the meaning of 事情がわって

Tags: words

First, I would like to yet thank all the community for your great exchange work ! I wish I can participate one day when I get a better understanding of japanese language.

I am learning japanese as an autodidact and so i try different type of exercices. One of them is to study some texts coming from the anime キャプテン翼 [Captain Tsubasa]. I put japanese audio with english subtitles.

In episode 2, 翼 (the hero) receives a letter from his father. We can see this letter on screen, but the quality back in 1983 and handwritten style makes it sometimes quite hard to decrypt. The aim of this question is not to ask for translation of the letter, but rather understand some parts of it that I could not do by myself despite my researches.

The context : 翼 receives a letter from his father explaining him that a famous brazilian footballer has to come from Brazil and stay at 翼 house for a while.

In the letter, we find the following sentence (as least if i could read it well) :
事{じ}情{じょう}がわって当{とう}分{ぶん}の間{あいだ}、日本にいることになったんだ。
[For personal reasons, he will stay at our house in Japan for a while].

I am there in trouble with the 事情がわって part. I can't understand what がわって stands for. The best I could find is maybe the using of 変{か}わる verb which might lead to [for changing reasons] or [because of a change in his state of being]. But the problem is that 変 reads か, not が, so I think my explanation is certainly wrong.

Does anyone have a better understanding of this word/verb ? It will be very interesting to get any other point of view in order to understand this sentence the best way.

Thank you in advance,

Natsu

Comment: 「事情が**あ**って」でもないんですよね・・？

Comment: @Chocolate : indeed, it may be that character ! The letter in the anime is quite hard to read, so I may have mistaken あ for わ... In addition to that, it is the first time I see あって, so it never came to my mind that this could be the right word. Thank you for your help !